# mapping a numpy array to a function, passing along the indices

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, dictionary

I have trained per-pixel models on many images and want to evaluate them on new images.

What I'd like to do is for each image of shape (N, M, 3), apply a function in this fashion:

```
myfunc(array[i, j, :], i, j)

# Takes (3,1) input and indices
def myfunc(input, i, j):

 ret1, ret2 = model[i,j].predict(input)

 # returns a single float value
 return ret1[1]
```

where i, j are indices, where myfunc will look up the correct model parameters to apply.  If it helps, model can be a numpy array of objects, with the same dimensions as the original input's first two dimensions (N, M)

I was looking at ufuncs and vectorize and wasn't really sure if they did what I wanted. Is there a provided interface for doing this, or will I have to loop through the array myself (ugly and possibly slower as it is in python).

Alternatively, what about applying the same function to each value?

e.g.

```
myfunc(array[i, j, :])

# Takes (3,1) input
def myfunc(input):

 ret1, ret2 = model.predict(input)

 # returns a single float value
 return ret1[1]
```

Comment: It is impossible to say without seeing the definition of `myfunc`.

Comment: @unutbu I'm asking for the simplest case: is it possible to pass indices? the function will return one value for each call, doesn't need neighbor access, etc. I added sample code.

Comment: `np.vectorize` only adds syntactic sugar. Under the hood, its implementation is essentially a Python `for-loop`. (See [the footnote in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).) Since your `myfunc` requires calling `predict` once for each value of `(i, j)`, and since there is no NumPy-based way to vectorize that, there is no real benefit here to using NumPy.

Comment: Syntatic sugar by itself is fine in that case, but I can't see how to use vectorize to get that.  Alternatively, what about applying the same function without indices along the depth axes?